# Cannot compile autogenerated JOOQ code because of multiple java errors

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jooq

I used `java --add-modules java.xml.bind -classpath jooq-3.11.3.jar;jooq-meta-3.11.3.jar;jooq-codegen-3.11.3.jar;postgresql-42.2.4.jar;. org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool jooq.xml` to autogenerate JOOQ code for my PostgreSQL 10 `USER` table.

[image: pgadmin4_2018-07-24_08-08-49]

The codegen tool finishes successfully however my program won´t compile because there are several Java syntax errors in the autogenerated code.

Some examples:

`PgClass.java`

```
/**
* @deprecated Unknown data type. Please define an explicit {@link org.jooq.Binding} to specify how this type should be handled. Deprecation can be turned off using <deprecationOnUnknownTypes/> in your code generator configuration.
*/
@java.lang.Deprecated
public final TableField<PgClassRecord, Object> RELPARTBOUND = createField("relpartbound", , this, "");
```

[image: idea64_2018-07-24_08-12-48]

The compiler is telling me `java: illigal start of expression`

`PgIndex.java:`

```
/**
* The column <code>pg_catalog.pg_index.indoption</code>.
*/
public final TableField<PgIndexRecord, Object[]> INDOPTION = createField("indoption", .getArrayDataType(), this, "");
```

[image: idea64_2018-07-24_08-15-31]

The compiler is telling me `java: as of release 8, 'this' is allowed as the parameter name for the receiver type only, which has to be the first parameter`

**EDIT:**

`jooq.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd">
  <jdbc>
    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/timecoder-api-dev</url>
    <user>postgres</user>
    <password></password>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
      <includes>.*</includes>
    </database>
    <target>
      <packageName>persistence.database.generated</packageName>
      <directory>K:\Data\Dev\Git\timecoder-api\src</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

- jOOQ: 3.11.3
- Java: 1.8.0_181
- Database (include vendor): PostgreSQL 10
- OS: Windows 10

I also created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7684

Comment: Will this work if done with an older version of Java?

Comment: can you post your jooq.xml? i don't think this is a jooq-issue - it seems you are including all schemas instead of just the one you need

Comment: Added jooq.xml to the post. Please take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. This is a bug in the code generator: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7692

It will be fixed in jOOQ 3.12.0 and 3.11.4

Answer (score 3):

My database tables are in Postgres schema "public".
I forgot to add `<inputSchema>public</inputSchema>` to my jooq.xml. Now it´s working fine :)

`jooq.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd">
  <jdbc>
    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/timecoder-api-dev</url>
    <user>postgres</user>
    <password></password>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
      <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
      <includes>.*</includes>
    </database>
    <target>
      <packageName>persistence.database.generated</packageName>
      <directory>K:\Data\Dev\Git\timecoder-api\src</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```